# Virtualbox host Win10 guest Fedora: problem with TexStudio: cannot overwrite .tex file

Tags: virtualbox, glib

I have Fedora 29 installed on a windows 10 host virtualbox. My main goal was to use this set up to work on some LaTeX documents. After going through all installations, updates etc.  I begin editing my paper, but the editor (TexStudio) won't overwrite `.tex` documents. Wasn't long until I realized that GUI text editors, namely xed, notepadqq etc. also refused to overwrite text files. `vi` worked, but, my target was to use TexStudio and finish up some pending papers.

All search results converged to the same point: An incompatibility between VirtualBox and 'glib'.

[Link to the main ticket on gitlab](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/glib/issues/438)

I am wondering if anyone found a work around.

I could use windows to run the tex engine, but given that majority of my files, scripts etc. are on linux, it would be the most convenient to compile tex documents in the linux environment.

Answer (score 0):

## Simple work around

Do the work in Ubuntu (not shared directory), and move files manually between systems, using shared directory.

## Better solution (I did this when I had similar/same problem)

Use mercurial: it is a revision control tool (you should be using one of these anyway). Use it to synchronise you work with bitbucker, and any other computers/the host.